# Function in for () loop: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare

Tags: php, function, for-loop, fatal-error

I have [this](http://pastebin.com/pND5v1N9) code, but when I try to execute it, it gives the following error:
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare genereerLiveCodeP() (previously declared in livestream.php:33) in livestream.php on line 32.`

```
session_start();

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//header("location: index.php");
if($_SESSION['***'] == '***'){
$fp = fopen("test.html", 'w');
fwrite($fp, "");
fwrite($fp, '<p class="green">*** is online</p>');



$result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM ***");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$rows = $row[0]+1000;

echo "Rows: ".$rows."\n";

for ($id = 1000; $id < $rows; $id++) {

echo "ID: ".$id."\n";

function genereerLiveCodeP () {
        $lengthCode = 6;
        $characters = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $liveCodeFunction = '';

        for ($p = 0; $p < $lengthCode; $p++) {
        $liveCodeFunction .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $liveCodeFunction;
}

$livecode = genereerLiveCodeP ();

echo "Livecode: ".$livecode."\n";

$x = mysql_query("UPDATE *** SET livecode='".$livecode."' WHERE *** = '".$***."'");

echo $x."\n";

}



}
```

What should I do?

Comment: for a start, what you should do: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. In addition, **escape/prepare your SQL**

Comment: Thank you. I will update my code soon (before I launch the website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the `for` loop before declaring the `function`. Your code should look like this:

```
...
for ($id = 1000; $id < $rows; $id++) {
echo "ID: ".$id."\n";
}

function genereerLiveCodeP () {
...
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they want the stuff after the function definition inside of the `for` loop still, so the function would have to be moved above the `for` loop.

Comment: I need to do it more times. For every row there must be a unique code set.

Comment: But the function is still always the same. Just move it out of the loop and try again.

Comment: I have placed it above `for ($id = 1000; $id < $rows; $id++) {`, but the file doesn't echo anything.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are using a deprecated extension ([`ext/mysql`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/)).

You need to move your function outside of the `for` loop. PHP doesn't work that way (redeclaring a function isn't possible, hence the error)

You can get a bigger boost in performance if you use a prepared query, and have far more future-proof code (your code will break in PHP 5.5 when those functions start throwing errors)

```
session_start();
$db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
function generate_live_code($length = 6) {
    $characters = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $str .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return $str;
}

//header("location: index.php");
if($_SESSION['id'] == 'debug') {
    $fp = fopen("test.html", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, "");
    fwrite($fp, '<p class="green">*** is online</p>');
    // writing html to a file? consider using a database...
    $result = $db->query("select count(1) FROM x");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
    $rows = $row[0]+1000;

    echo "Rows: $rows\n"; // no need to concat with double quotes.
    if ($query = $db->prepare("UPDATE x SET livecode = ? WHERE id = ?")) {
        for ($id = 1000; $id < $rows; $id++) {
            echo "ID: ".$id."\n";
            $livecode = generate_live_code();
            echo "Livecode: $livecode\n";
            $query->bind_param("si", $livecode, $id);
            $query->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting the function outside the loop did it ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring function `genereerLiveCodeP()` inside a loop, try to put it at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Luuksweb it is impossible to declare a function inside a loop in PHP that loops more than once. Don't do it.

Comment: But how can I do that for every id a unique code is generated?